In The Leibnizian Cosmological Argument, is it allowed for necessary being to have alternatives(like different versions of that category)?
In the Argument of Contingency and Leibnizian Cosmological Argument, it is said that if something could have been diffferent then that thing can not be necessary. My question is can a simultaneosly existing being be necessary rather than god, like a different god or system. And by system let’s say X system is able to create universe, and let’s say there is Y existance simultaneously existing, and if we assume that they are both existing, they are both alternatives to each other but they do not restrict their necessity. How can we say that, this system can not be necessary thru using alternatives example?
And here is the definition of Alternatives, I like to divide the definition to 2 to have easy understanding.
A1 and A2, A1 is something that changes or able to change but it is identically same thing(like my 5 years old state and my current state. It is still me but my changed version.). A2 is things that stays in same category but different versions, Like God Zeus and Abrahamic God, they are not identically same but they both are Gods in the context ( for example, in the context of humans, me and my friend are alternatives to each other.).
Using A1 and A2 will help me lot more for this question.
Have a good day.

Proponents of the argument usually give auxiliary arguments to rule out multiple necessary beings. Pruss says "if there were multiple necessary beings, we would not expect to see a nomically unified world". Hsiao and Sanders argue that necessary beings must all have identical properties and hence must be the same by identity of indiscernibles or principle of sufficient reason, etc.

Thank you sir, but what if necessaey being was something other than god? And can you send me his article?
